# How to setup a plugin?

Tags: qt, plugins, qt5

I've written a qt application to communicate to a custom controller over RS232.  I now need to extend functionality to the application through a plugin.  I've looked at the Echo Plugin Example provided online and what else I can find elsewhere online but I am still pretty lost and the very basic plugin is not compiling.  the project .pro file for the plugin is as follows:

```
TEMPLATE        = lib                                       # making a library, not an executible
CONFIG         += plugin                                    #
QT             += widgets network gui
INCLUDEPATH    += ../vibecreator/vibecreator/               # include path to plugin interface
TARGET          = $$qtLibraryTarget(reactionsserverplugin)  # name of the library file in which the plugin will be stored, should be same as name of the plugin
DESTDIR         = ../plugins

# install
target.path = ../plugins
INSTALLS += target

CONFIG += install_ok  # Do not cargo-cult this!

SOURCES += reactionsserverplugin.cpp

HEADERS  += reactionsserverplugin.h \
    reactionsserverinterface.h

FORMS += \
    reactionfileform.ui

DISTFILES += \
    reactionsserver.plugin.json
```

The header file is

```
#ifndef REACTIONSSERVER_PLUGIN_H
#define REACTIONSSERVER_PLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtPlugin>

//#include "../vibecreator/vibecreator/reactionsserverinterface.h"
#include "reactionsserverinterface.h"

namespace Ui {
    class ReactionServerFileForm;
}

class ReactionsServerPlugin : public QWidget, ReactionsServerInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA( IID "org.qt-project.Qt.AddHaptics.ReactionsServerInterface" FILE "reactionsserver.plugin.json" )
    Q_INTERFACES(ReactionsServerInterface)

public:
    void createForm() override;

private:
    Ui::ReactionServerFileForm* ui;

};

#endif // REACTIONSSERVER_GLOBAL_H
```

The source file is:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "reactionsserverplugin.h"
#include "ui_reactionfileform.h"

void ReactionsServerPlugin::createForm()
{
    ui = new Ui::ReactionServerFileForm;
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Below is the interface class

```
#ifndef REACTIONSSERVER_INTERFACE_H
#define REACTIONSSERVER_INTERFACE_H

class ReactionsServerInterface
{

public:
    virtual ~ReactionsServerInterface(){}
    virtual void createForm();
};

#define ReactinonsSeverInterface_iid "org.qt-project.Qt.AddHaptics.ReactionsServerInterface"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ReactionsServerInterface, ReactinonsSeverInterface_iid)

#endif // REACTIONSSERVER_H
```

I am getting the following  error and as far as I can tell, I don't have any code to fail.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for ReactionsServerInterface", referenced from:
      typeinfo for ReactionsServerPlugin in moc_reactionsserverplugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [../plugins/libreactionsserverplugin_debug.dylib] Error 1
13:07:00: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project reactionsserverplugin (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I've searched online for a resolution to this error but haven't found any results.

Comment: Please show your ReactionsServerInterface class declaration. Are you calling Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE?

Comment: I've added the interface class to the original post.  Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE is ReactionsServerInterface

Answer (score 0):

The typeinfo error seems typically related to the declaration of a virtual function.  The problem was indeed in the inferface class.  The declaration for the  createForm function in the interface class should be as follows

```
virtual void createForm() = 0;
```